# Show decimals in Groovy division

Tags: math, groovy, division

I'm sure this is a very simple question but I'm stuck. I'm new to Groovy.

Let's say I have:

```
Long percentageFee = 285   
percentageFee = percentageFee / 100     //Display as 2.85%
```

I've tried this several ways, casting `percentageFee` to `double`, etc, but the result is still just 2.

I must be getting the syntax wrong or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a decimal place to either one of the operands then it isn't integer division anymore:

```
groovy:000> percentageFee = 285L
===> 285
groovy:000> percentageFee / 100.0
===> 2.85
```

Here 100.0 is a BigDecimal.

If this was Java then dividing a long with an integer would result in a long. But in Groovy it doesn't work like that. The division operation returns a BigDecimal, assigning the result to a Long truncates the result:

```
groovy:000> percentageFee = 285L
===> 285
groovy:000> f = percentageFee / 100
===> 2.85
groovy:000> f.class
===> class java.math.BigDecimal
```

(Thanks to [blackdrag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938573/blackdrag) for the clarification.)

Comment: An addition... the showed code works correctly, but he is not doing integer devision. The reason he gets only 2 is that he assigns the result to percentageFee, which is a Long. This will cause the BigDecimal created by the devision to be converted to a Long, thus he looses all the parts behind the dot. Not using a type solves the problem. Using for example double (or Float or BigDecimal) for percentageFee would have solved it as well

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in a more "Groovy" way, taking advantage of what makes Groovy so *groovy* -- dynamically typed variables.

```
def percentageFee = 285   
percentageFee = percentageFee.div(100)
assert percentageFee == 2.85
```

This may not fit your specific situation and is not as concise or simple as adding a decimal and a zero.

:-)

[See the Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-integer-divisions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
def percentageFee = 285.0
percentageFee = percentageFee / 100
println percentageFee
```

Result is `2.85`